# Irregular responsive grid of hexagons

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to generate the following image using CSS and media queries :

[image]

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.honeycombs = function (options) {

        // Establish our default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            combWidth: 210,
            margin: 30
        }, options);

 /*       var windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth;
        console.log('windowWidth:',windowWidth);
        if (windowWidth <= 992) {
            settings.combWidth = 120;
            settings.margin = 30;
            console.log('combWidth:', settings.combWidth);
        }
*/
        function initialise(element) {

            $(element).addClass('honeycombs-wrapper');

            var width = 0;
            var combWidth = 0;
            var combHeight = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var $wrapper = null;


            /**
             * Build the dom
             */
            function buildHtml() {
                // add the 2 other boxes
                $(element).find('.comb').wrapAll('<div class="honeycombs-inner-wrapper"></div>');
                $wrapper = $(element).find('.honeycombs-inner-wrapper');

                $(element).find('.comb').append('<div class="hex_l"></div>');
                $(element).find('.hex_l').append('<div class="hex_r"></div>');
                $(element).find('.hex_r').append('<div class="hex_inner"></div>');

                $(element).find('.hex_inner').append('<div class="inner_span"><div class="inner-text"></div></div>');

                num = 0;

                $(element).find('.comb').each(function () {
                    num = num + 1;
                    var image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                    var css = 'url("' + image + '") ';

                    $(this).find('.hex_inner').attr('style', 'background-image: ' + css);

                    if ($(this).find('span').length > 0) {
                        $(this).find('.inner_span .inner-text').html($(this).find('span').html());
                    } else {
                        $(this).find('.inner_span').remove();
                    };
                });

                $(element).find('img, span, .inner_span').hide();
            }

            /**
             * Update all scale values
             */
            function updateScales() {
                combWidth = settings.combWidth;
                combHeight = (Math.sqrt(3) * combWidth) / 2;
                edgeWidth = combWidth / 2;


                $(element).find('.comb').width(combWidth).height(combHeight);
                $(element).find('.hex_l, .hex_r').width(combWidth).height(combHeight);
                $(element).find('.hex_inner').width(combWidth).height(combHeight);
            }

            /**
             * update css classes
             */
            function reorder(animate) {

                updateScales();
                width = $(element).width();

                newWidth = (num / 1.5) * settings.combWidth;

                if (newWidth < width) {
                    width = newWidth;
                }

                $wrapper.width(width);

                var row = 0; // current row
                var upDown = 1; // 1 is down
                var left = 0; // pos left
                var top = 0; // pos top

                var cols = 0;

                $(element).find('.comb').each(function (index) {

                    top = (row * (combHeight + settings.margin)) + (upDown * (combHeight / 2 + (settings.margin / 2)));

                    if (animate == true) {
                        $(this).stop(true, false);
                        $(this).animate({
                            'left': left,
                            'top': top
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('left', left).css('top', top);
                    }

                    left = left + (combWidth - combWidth / 4 + settings.margin);
                    upDown = (upDown + 1) % 2;

                    if (row == 0) {
                        cols = cols + 1;
                    }

                    if (left + combWidth > width) {
                        left = 0;
                        row = row + 1;
                        upDown = 1;
                    }
                });

                $wrapper
                    .width(cols * (combWidth / 4 * 3 + settings.margin) + combWidth / 4)
                    .height((row + 1) * (combHeight + settings.margin) + combHeight / 2);
            }

            /*  $(window).resize(function(){
                reorder(true);
            });
*/


            $(element).find('.comb').mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).find('.inner_span').stop(true, true);
                $(this).find('.inner_span').fadeIn();
            });

            $(element).find('.comb').mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).find('.inner_span').stop(true, true);
                $(this).find('.inner_span').fadeOut();
            });



            buildHtml();
            reorder(false);
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            initialise(this);
        });

    }

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.honeycombs {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.honeycombs .inner_span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f7cd07;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.honeycombs .inner-text {
    padding-top: 30%;
}

.honeycombs .honeycombs-inner-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    height: 1200px;
}

.honeycombs .comb {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.honeycombs .hex_l,
.honeycombs .hex_r {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; */
}

.honeycombs .hex_l {
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.honeycombs .hex_r {
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-120deg);
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.honeycombs .hex_inner {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .honeycombs .comb {
        /*width: 100px;
        height: 100px;*/
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body >
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.honeycombs').honeycombs();
        });
    </script>


<div class="container">
    <section id="home-section">
        <article>
            <div class="honeycombs">
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb">
                    <img src="http://www.sketchoholic.com/uploads/old_files/12951/phoenix.jpg" />
                    <span>Image Caption 3</span>
                </div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"> <img src="http://cdn.skim.gs/images/c_fill,dpr_1.0,h_391,w_695/s5y5lg53667serkntwa8/unique-female-dog-names" /> <span>Image Caption 6</span></div>
                <div class="comb"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/700" /> <span>Image Caption 7</span></div>
                <div class="comb"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Pavo_cristatus_-Castellar_Zoo%2C_Castellar_de_la_Frontera%2C_Spain-8a.png" /> <span>Image Caption 7</span></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"> <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/188b4f88-93d6-4810-a7b0-0aaf7df5375b/c45bda98-8119-421a-b338-160a7532da77.jpg" /> <span>Image Caption 12</span></div>
                <div class="comb"> <img src="http://monangebebe.m.o.pic.centerblog.net/piayisjw.jpg" /> <span>Image Caption 13</span></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
                <div class="comb"></div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The following image is the one that I am getting on my desktop (large screen) with the above code. However, on small sized screen I am not able to resize the hexagons to make it responsive. Also, is it possible to generate the lines in between the hexagons?

[image]

Thanking you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two sections.
**Responsiveness**
In order for anything to be responsive on the web you have two options. CSS solution and JavaScript solution.

CSS
To declare its width, height, padding (if you are working with pseudo-elements) in a percentage form and not exactly the pixels.
For example:

```
.honeycombs .honeycombs-inner-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;    ->>  width: 20%
    position: relative;
    height: 1200px;  ->>  height: 50%
}
```

JavaScript
You can check the browser width and customize the height,width of your blocks accordingly.

```
if($(window).width() < 860) {
    $('.honeycombs .honeycombs-inner-wrapper').css('width','250px');
}
```

**Inlines**
You can use an HTML5 canvas to draw SVG on the container. Check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) about the canvas element.

Comment: I have tried changing the px to percentage and working with the following in my JS file :
    if ($(window).width() < 860) {
            settings.combWidth = 110;
            settings.margin = 5;

        }
It doesn't help

For the lines i was refering to the outside white lines between the hexagons. Is it possible to make the line in CSS?